# is it possible to manually restart celery task

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using celery 3 with django and flower to monitor  tasks.

is there any way that if

1. my task fail
2. then i do some fix in code
3. Then i get the task id and then rstart that task

Is it possible

or even a way to manually place any failed task in another queue so that it can be processes again after fixing the cause of it

Comment: You can restart the entire celery, but not a single task (a task is just a item in a queue), however you can reschedule your task for when you need, you can see how to do it here https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/reference/celery.task.html

Comment: @trinchet but i can't decide before hand when to reshedule it. Suppose there was my bad code which failed the task . I think fixed my code and then i want to retry that task

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a hack, but what works for me is creating a new task instance with the same task ID. For example, a task with ID 'abc' runs and fails. I then "restart" the task by running:

```
my_task.apply_async(args=('whatever'), task_id='abc')
```

In reality it is less of a "restart" and more just a replacement of the original task result, but it gets the job done. Definitely open to better suggestions here as it does feel a bit clumsy.